# Check Multiple condition for same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have to compare 2 different sources and identify all the mismatches for all `IDs`

`Source_excel` table

```
+-----+-------------+------+----------+
| id  | name        | City | flag     |
+-----+-------------+------+----------+
| 101 | Plate       | NY   | Ready    |
| 102 | Back washer | NY   | Sold     |
| 103 | Ring        | MC   | Planning |
| 104 | Glass       | NMC  | Ready    |
| 107 | Cover       | PR   | Ready    |
+-----+-------------+------+----------+
```

`Source_dw` table

```
+-----+----------+------+----------+
| id  | name     | City | flag     |
+-----+----------+------+----------+
| 101 | Plate    | NY   | Planning |
| 102 | Nut      | TN   | Expired  |
| 103 | Ring     | MC   | Planning |
| 104 | Top Wire | NY   | Ready    |
| 105 | Bolt     | MC   | Expired  |
+-----+----------+------+----------+
```

Expected result

```
+-----+-------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
| ID  | excel_name  | dw_name  | excel_flag | dw_flag  | excel_city | dw_city | RESULT           |
+-----+-------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
| 101 | Plate       | Plate    | Ready      | Planning | NY         | NY      | FLAG_MISMATCH    |
| 102 | Back washer | Nut      | Sold       | Expired  | NY         | TN      | NAME_MISMATCH    |
| 102 | Back washer | Nut      | Sold       | Expired  | NY         | TN      | FLAG_MISMATCH    |
| 102 | Back washer | Nut      | Sold       | Expired  | NY         | TN      | CITY_MISMATCH    |
| 103 | Ring        | Ring     | Planning   | Planning | MC         | MC      | ALL_MATCH        |
| 104 | Glass       | Top Wire | Ready      | Ready    | NMC        | NY      | NAME_MISMATCH    |
| 104 | Glass       | Top Wire | Ready      | Ready    | NMC        | NY      | CITY_MISMATCH    |
| 107 | Cover       |          | Ready      |          | PR         |         | MISSING IN DW    |
| 105 |             | Bolt     |            | Expired  |            | MC      | MISSING IN EXCEL |
+-----+-------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------------+
```

I'm new to python and I have tried the below query but it not giving the expected result.

```
import pandas as pd

source_excel = pd.read_csv('C:/Mypython/Newyork/excel.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
source_dw = pd.read_csv('C:/Mypython/Newyork/dw.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
comparison_result = pd.merge(source_excel,source_dw,on='ID',how='outer',indicator=True)

 
comparison_result.loc[(comparison_result['_merge'] == 'both') & (name_x != name_y), 'Result'] = 'NAME_MISMATCH' 
comparison_result.loc[(comparison_result['_merge'] == 'both') & (city_x != city_y), 'Result'] = 'CITY_MISMATCH'
comparison_result.loc[(comparison_result['_merge'] == 'both') & (flag_x != flag_y), 'Result'] = 'FLAG_MISMATCH'     
comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == 'left_only', 'Result'] = 'Missing in dw'  
comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == 'right_only', 'Result'] = 'Missing in excel'  
comparison_result.loc[comparison_result['_merge'] == 'both', 'Result'] = 'ALL_Match' 

csv_column = comparison_result[['ID','name_x','name_y','city_x','city_y','flag_x','flag_y','Result']]
print(csv_column)
```

Is there any other way I can check all the condition and report each in separate row. If separate row not possible, atleast i need in same column separated by all mismatches. something like `FLAG_MISMATCH,CITY_MISMATCH`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df = pd.merge(Source_excel, Source_dw, on = 'ID', how = 'left', suffixes = (None, '_dw'))
```

This will create a new dataframe like the one you want, although you'll have to reorder the columns as you want. Note that the **'_dw'** is a suffix and not a prefix in this case.

You can reorder the columns as you like by using this code:

```
#Complement with the order you want
df = df[['ID', 'excel_name']]
```

For the result column I think you'll have to create a column for each condition you're trying to check (at least that's the way I know how to). Here's an example:

```
#This will return 1 if there's a match and 0 otherwise
df['result_flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.excel_flag == x.flag_dw else 0, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the scoring:

```
df['result'] = 0

# repeated mask / df.loc statements suggests a loop, over a list of tuples
mask = df['excel_flag'] != df['df_flag']
df.loc[mask, 'result'] += 1

mask = df['excel_name'] != df['dw_name']
df.loc[mask, 'result'] += 10

df['result'] = df['result'].map({ 0: 'all match',
                                  1: 'flag mismatch',
                                 10: 'name mismatch',
                                 11: 'all mismatch',})
```